# Error when upgrading to Rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying ro upgrade my app to rails 3.1.1. I am following the [railscasts tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1?view=asciicast), so I first updated to 3.0.9. I had a few problems with will_paginate but they were solved after updating to a newer version. Now all my tests are passing and I am trying to update to 3.1.1

So I have modified my Gemfile to use Rails 3.1.1, but when I do `bundle update`, I get the following output (with some ruby errors in it, and a message about installing the development tools first).

Edit: starting to think this has something to do with not having upgraded xcode after installing OSX Lion. Could it be that? I am downloading it now but it's going to take a while...

```
MacBoo:myapp oalo$ bundle update
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using ZenTest (4.6.2) 
Using multi_json (1.0.3) 
Using activesupport (3.1.1) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using activemodel (3.1.1) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.3.5) 
Using rack-cache (1.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.8.3) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.0.3) 
Using actionpack (3.1.1) 
Using mime-types (1.17.1) 
Using polyglot (0.3.2) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.3.0) 
Using actionmailer (3.1.1) 
Using arel (2.2.1) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.30) 
Using activerecord (3.1.1) 
Using activeresource (3.1.1) 
Using annotate (2.4.0) 
Using autotest (4.4.6) 
Installing sys-uname (0.8.6) with native extensions /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:552:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for sysctl()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
/Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:435:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:440:in `try_link'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:552:in `try_func'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:797:in `block in have_func'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:796:in `have_func'
    from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sys-uname-0.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sys-uname-0.8.6/ext/gem_make.out
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:530:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:505:in `each'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:505:in `build_extensions'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:180:in `install'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/source.rb:101:in `block in install'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:78:in `preserve_paths'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/source.rb:91:in `install'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:93:in `with_build_args'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:57:in `block in run'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:49:in `run'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/cli.rb:270:in `update'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.15/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
MacBoo:myapp oalo$
```

Comment: What's in `/Users/oalo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/sys-uname-0.8.6/ext/gem_make.out`?

Comment: @DouglasFShearer http://pastebin.com/wRJru6rR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually updating rvm fixes the 'You have to install development tools first' error:

```
rvm get latest
rvm reload
rvm --force install 1.9.2
```

What do you have in the mkmf.log?

Comment: I get an error when trying to use the first command: 'ERROR: rvm update has been removed. See 'rvm get' and rvm 'rubygems' CLI API instead'. Also, cant find mkmf.log anywhere, where should I look?

Comment: Hello, you are right. rvm udpate is deprecated. I updated my reply. I don't now the exact path to mkmf.log; assuming you are in *nix you can search it in you file system using the following command: find / -name mkmf.log

Comment: Thanks Paulo, I had already tried searching with that command, and no results... I am going to try the new rvm command

Comment: I did this and also installed the newest version of Xcode (I didnt since upgrading to Lion), so I am not sure which of both fixed the problem, but now it works so I leave this comment in case its useful to anyone.